# Reference request for the number of solvents around a solute

Tags: solubility, solutions, reference-request, solvents

I want to know if there is a way to find number of solvent molecules that are **directly** embracing a solute molecule (something like a reference or table that shows **waters of hydration**).

Particularly I am interested in solvents such as water or ethanol, and the solutes acetone, acetaldehyde, 1-butanol, methylene blue, benzene, anthracene, and phenanthrene.

Comment: This is too broad. For a single atom ion this would sort of be answerable. But there are large molecules like proteins or polymers where the solute molecule could contact hundreds (or more) of solvent molecules.